# Erratic behaviour in response express + next + react with concurrent requests

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I have a Node app running with ExpressJS, Next and React and this app loads dynamically different layouts based on a header it receives. This header is set by Nginx in the virtualhost. So imagine 3 different domains which has to load this same app, but each virtualhost has a different value in this header, so this is what the app reads and returns the right layout.

This approach works as expected until 2 requests with different value in this header arrives at the same time. When that happens, the response from one of them could be overlapped with the other completely or partially some times.

I am aware of the functionality of app.local and request.local which works to isolate request/response but after playing with it, it doesn't fix my problem, or maybe I am using it the wrong way.

At this link you can see the software architecture concept of the app (simplified). If you want to reproduce the error, you would have to set up 2 virtualhosts with this header with different value and load both domains at once:

https://codesandbox.io/s/zmoq4q3mp

Any help would be appreciate.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is simple, you're assigning the current template to `config.layoutTpl`, which is a singleton shared across the whole application, it's not unique to that request.

So basically, all the requests are modifying the same `config` object, and that's why you have the issue. When working with concurrency, you can't use "globals", otherwise you're going to get this sort of issues.

You have to pass the data to `_document.js` from `_app.js`, or fetch the template directly in `_document.js` which is the only place where you're using it right now.

The following will work, even though there might be a better approach on how to pass the data around in next.

What you need to do instead of assigning the template, to `config`, assign it to `ctx` which is unique for each request.

**_app.js**

```
export default withRedux(initStore)(
  class MyApp extends App {
    static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {

      let layoutTpl = null;
      if (ctx.req && !process.browser) {
        const { layouttpl } = ctx.req.headers;
        layoutTpl = layouttpl;
      }

      // Assign the current template, to the context
      // This is unique for this specific request
      ctx.layoutTpl = layoutTpl || config.layoutTpl;

      return {
        pageProps: Component.getInitialProps
          ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
          : {}
      };
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

**_document.js**

```
// import config from "../config";

// I'm passing the template directly, instead of the config object here
const varJs = layoutTpl => `
var layoutTpl = "${layoutTpl}";
`;

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {

    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    // get the value from `ctx` and use it in `render`
    return { ...initialProps, layoutTpl: ctx.layoutTpl };
  }

  render() {
    const { layoutTpl } = this.props;
    // Get the layoutTpl which is unique to this request
    return (
      <html>
        <Head>
          <base href="/" />
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=3,minimal-ui"
          />
          <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: varJs(layoutTpl) }} />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What you said actually helped me with half the problem, but I keep having the problem when trying to set the headers from a request coming to the server render to a request to an external api. How could I pass my context headers to that other request. I've updated my demo to show you the problem. Do I need to instantiate AXIOS for every request setting in each instantiation the headers? Would this affect performance?

Comment: Each request is a new "instance", so you already instanciate axios every time you do a request, that won't affect performance.